# Php variable result

Tags: php, variables, serialization

```
$name= path1
$key= key1
    public static function getpath($name, $key)
      {
        if (!self::is_valid($name, $key)) return false;
        $path = '/var/lib/fdata/'.$name.'/'.$key;
        if (!is_file($path)) return false;
        return $path;
      }

      public static function get($name, $key)
      {
        $path = self::getpath($name, $key);
        if ($path === false) return false;
        return file_get_contents($path);
      }

    $configmap = unserialize(fdata::get('base', 'key'));
```

The questions is:

1. if variable `$path = self::getpath($name, $key);` then $path = ? and what mean `self::`
2. if variable `$configmap = unserialize(fdata::get('base', 'key'));` then $configmap = ? and what mean `fdata::`

Comment: @iccthedral Nobody was born a programmer :) It all takes time and practice. It is best to get customary usage of a language down through reading language books, tutorials, online documentation, and some practice. SO is a good place to ask a *specific* question focusing on a particular point of interest. It is not such a good place to get explanations of "standard" code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `self::getpath(...)` should return a boolean value or a string. `self::` refers to a current class.

2) [Here's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the man for `unserialize`

3) 
 `fdata::` denotes the namespace fdata or perhaps a class.